# ExportToPdf returns 0KB

Tags: c#, telerik, radeditor

I have used the Telerik RadEditor and the `ExportToPdf` method in C# but
when the PDF is downloaded it contains 0KB, but it contains data in the RadEditor content.

This is my code:

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" SkinID="DefaultSetOfTools"
Height="515px" Visible="false" ContentFilters="DefaultFilters,PdfExportFilter">
    <ExportSettings OpenInNewWindow="true" FileName="ErinLetter">
    </ExportSettings>
    <ImageManager ViewPaths="~/PDFbarcode" UploadPaths="~/PDFbarcode" DeletePaths="~/PDFbarcode"></ImageManager>
</telerik:RadEditor>
<br />
<div align="right">
    <asp:Button ID="btnPdf" runat="server" CssClass="NFButton" Text="PDF" OnClick="btnPdf_Click" />
</div>
```

The content binds from the backend, for example:

```
<h2>Test RadEditor</h2>
```

but it returns 0KB.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the RadEditor's Visible property to true. I don't think export will work if it is false.

Also, compare your setup with the original here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/pdfexport/defaultcs.aspx and see what's the difference that breaks stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content inline in the declaration:

```
<telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="RadEditor1" SkinID="DefaultSetOfTools"
  Height="515px" Visible="false" ContentFilters="DefaultFilters,PdfExportFilter">
    <Content>
        <h2>Test RadEditor</h2>
    </Content>
    <ExportSettings OpenInNewWindow="true" FileName="ErinLetter">
    </ExportSettings>
    <ImageManager ViewPaths="~/PDFbarcode" UploadPaths="~/PDFbarcode" DeletePaths="~/PDFbarcode"></ImageManager>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

You can also hide the editor by wrapping it in a hidden